# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, mach-o

The following is the detailed error message I got while compiling a OpenCV project. Please help me out. Thanks a lot!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvFindFundamentalMat", referenced from:
      testRigidRegistrationCode() in AugmentedReality.o
      CamEgoMotion::step6_computeEssentialMatrix(CvMat*, CvMat*, bool*) in CameraEgomotion.o
  "_cvComputeCorrespondEpilines", referenced from:
      CamEgoMotion::step6_computeEssentialMatrix(CvMat*, CvMat*, bool*) in CameraEgomotion.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key there is "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64".  You're linking against a 32-bit library somewhere.  What library, we have no idea, since you didn't include enough information.